# piping output of find to tar: avoiding duplicate links to files in archive

Tags: tar

When piping the output of `find` to `tar`, two links for each file appear in the resulting archive. This is not the case if `tar` is applied to the directory directly. Can the duplicate links be avoided?

Here is an example:

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ for i in {1..3}; do echo "$i" > "tmp/$i"; done
$ ls tmp
1  2  3
$ tar -cvvf tmp.tar tmp | sort
drwxr-xr-x usr/grp   0 2019-05-02 15:09 tmp/
-rw-r--r-- usr/grp   2 2019-05-02 15:09 tmp/1
-rw-r--r-- usr/grp   2 2019-05-02 15:09 tmp/2
-rw-r--r-- usr/grp   2 2019-05-02 15:09 tmp/3
$ find tmp | tar -T - -cvvf tmp.tar | sort
drwxr-xr-x usr/grp   0 2019-05-02 15:09 tmp/
hrw-r--r-- usr/grp   0 2019-05-02 15:09 tmp/1 link to tmp/1
hrw-r--r-- usr/grp   0 2019-05-02 15:09 tmp/2 link to tmp/2
hrw-r--r-- usr/grp   0 2019-05-02 15:09 tmp/3 link to tmp/3
-rw-r--r-- usr/grp   2 2019-05-02 15:09 tmp/1
-rw-r--r-- usr/grp   2 2019-05-02 15:09 tmp/2
-rw-r--r-- usr/grp   2 2019-05-02 15:09 tmp/3
```

This was done with GNU tar 1.26.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by steeldriver, the problem was that `tar` received not only the files within the directory but the directory itself. The default behavior of `tar` is to recurse through directories, so each entry within the directory was added a second time (once by explicit provision of the files and once by recursion through the explicitly provided directory). The solution is either (1) to provide no directories or (2) to disable recursion.

The first would look like:

```
$ find tmp -type f -print0 | sort -z | tar --null -T - -cvvf tmp.tar
-rw-r--r-- usr/grp     2 2019-05-02 17:06 tmp/1
-rw-r--r-- usr/grp     2 2019-05-02 17:06 tmp/2
-rw-r--r-- usr/grp     2 2019-05-02 17:06 tmp/3
```

The second case (which I need since I want to reproduce a complete, nested directory structure) is to simply disable recursion:

```
$ find tmp -print0 | sort -z | tar --no-recursion --null -T - -cvvf tmp.tar
drwxr-xr-x usr/grp     0 2019-05-02 17:06 tmp/
-rw-r--r-- usr/grp     2 2019-05-02 17:06 tmp/1
-rw-r--r-- usr/grp     2 2019-05-02 17:06 tmp/2
-rw-r--r-- usr/grp     2 2019-05-02 17:06 tmp/3
```